# Perl CPAN Neo4p retrieve RETURN count object

Tags: perl, neo4j, cpan

I am using PERL's CPAN Neo4p module, already define a cypher query of Neo4j. But the return type is "count" function. Count for the numbers of return apgd results. The code is:

```
my $query = REST::Neo4p::Query->new(
   "match (apgd)-[:CURRENT_UNDER]->(status {status:'$cri'}),".
    "(apgd)-[:HAS_NAME]->(name), ".
    "(apgd)-[:HAS_SEQUENCE]->(sequence), ".
    "(apgd)-[:HOST_IN]->(host), ".
    "(apgd)-[:HAS_LAMP_ID]->(lampid), ".
    "(apgd)-[:FROM]->(source) ".
"return (apgd),(name),(sequence),(source),(lampid),(host),count(apgd)"
);
$query->execute;
```

It will return 7 objects. So there is another function to get the result,

```
    while (my $result = $query->fetch)
    {
    print $result->[0]->get_property('id')."\t”;
    print $result->[1]->get_property('name')."\t”;
    print $result->[2]->get_property('seq')."\t”;
    print $result->[6]->get_property('')."\n";
    }
```

About the line: 
    print $result->[6]->get_property('')."\n";

What is the property name? Thanks

Comment: Use Data::Dumper to view data structures: `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper($result)`

Answer (score 1):

`$result` is an arrayref that contains the items asked for in the RETURN clause. So, the first 6 items of the array are `REST::Neo4p::Node` objects, but the seventh is just a scalar, the value of count(agpd). That is, `$result->[6]` *is itself* the value of count(agpd), for each row.